# .htaccess rewrite using RedirectMatch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect several URL to one
FROM 
    1.example.com/groups/3d/
    2.example.com/groups/3d/skype:softlist_ua?chat
    3.example.com/groups/3d/+/
    4.example.com/groups/3d/+/+/
    5.example.com/groups/3d/+/skype:softlist_ua?chat

TO
example.com/catalog/3d/

Redirect statement works fine, however when old URL containts get reuqests, it adds this get request to end of the new URL. How can I remove it?

RedirectMatch 301 ^/groups/3d/.*$ /catalog/3d/$1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/groups/3d/.*$ /catalog/3d/?
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRUle ^groups/3d/ /catalog/3d/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: almost there. doesn't add the whole query but, stll adds ? sign to the end. :)

Comment: @user2992672 what query? You want to remove the query string, right? And your questions say you want everything to be redirected to `example.com/catalog/3d/`, not `example.com/catalog/3d/blahblah/`

Comment: yeap. everything to example.com/catalog/3d/. it works fine with example.com/groups/3d/ or example.com/groups/3d/*/ but for example.com/groups/3d/skype:softlist_ua?chat has ?chat part that transfers to new url, so I end up with example.com/catalog/3d/?chat

Comment: @user2992672 You can't get rid of the `?` using mod_alias, you need to use mod_rewrite. Make sure you have mod_rewrite turned on, see edit